# Open dialog with phonegap and jquery mobile usng a link

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, navigation

I want to open a dialog using jquery mobile and phonegap like this:

```
$('<a href="my-page-dialog.html" data-rel="dialog">').click();
```

Everytime that code is triggered, nothing happens... I've seen that opening dialogs programatically is very messy...

I want to do this because I need to display a message before showing some final page, but I don't want it to be a part of the navigation, so I can go backwards normally... A solution for that would be fine also, even if it doesn't involves dialogs...

Comment: $('#myPage').live('pageinit', function(event){                               alert("PhoneGap is Working");
});  try this. May be help

Answer (score 1):

if **my-page-dialog.html** contains a simple message, then you can use `alert()` and **phonegab** will show the appropriate native alert dialog.

Comment: Actually it contains an image